# Why is cpu_index_tuple_cost different from cpu_tuple_cost in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

What is the reason of the values of cpu_index_tuple_cost and cpu_tuple_cost being different?
Shouldn't it take the same amount of time, once the reader head is already reading that page?

I checked the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CPU-TUPLE-COST) and I expected cpu_index_tuple_cost and cpu_tuple_cost to be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Reader head” and “page” seem to suggest that disk I/O plays a role here, but the cost parameters for that are `random_page_cost` and `seq_page_cost`. `cpu_index_tuple_cost` and `cpu_tuple_cost` are about the CPU time spent processing a single index or table entry. Now index tuples are typically much smaller than table tuples, so estimating a lower cost is justified.

I dug into the history of that parameter, and it was introduced in [commit b1577a7c78](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=b1577a7c78d2d8880b3c0f94689fb75bd074c897) in 2000 with a value of 0.001, a tenth of `cpu_tuple_cost`. Later, it was decided that the value was too small (see the [discussion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/447F23A9.1090503%40agliodbs.com#29ba1460f6fb4f70ed984307f6ff9a33)), and [commit e4de635a2b](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e4de635a2ba10dcc6fdb972f87fb25953d8d3001) from 2006 changed the default value to 0.005.